# DAX Query To Filter To Latest Value

Tags: powerbi, dax

Within a Power BI report, I want to filter to the latest value in a column of timestamps. It is using a DirectQuery model so I can't use MAX in a calculate column, but I can use it in a measure. I need something along the lines of:

```
=IF(Query1[TimeStamp]=Calculate(Max(Query1[TimeStamp])),"Latest","")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the max for the whole column by removing the filter context:

```
CALCULATE(MAX(Query1[TimeStamp]), ALL(Query1[TimeStamp]))
```

The whole measure would look like this:

```
= IF(MAX(result[Fecha]) = CALCULATE(MAX(result[Fecha]), ALL(result[Fecha])),
    "Latest", "")
```